# Regex pattern validation not working properly in angular 11

Tags: angular, regex, validation

My type script code to restrict only alphabets:

```
InputValidatorChar(event:any){

    Const pattern= /^[a-zA-Z]*$/;
    If(!      pattern.test(event.target.value)){
event.target.value=event.target.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z/g,"");
}}
```

Expected output: Should accept only alphabets (example: jekrhrjek)

Output I am getting: Accepting only characters. But if I type any integer at end of the sentence as input and click outside of cell then the last typed integer is getting populated.

How to overcome this problem?

Comment: Can you show a simple Stackblitz example, or some code?

Comment: You also have a typo in here: ...`[^a-zA-Z/g`...  after the `A-Z` *missing closing*  `]`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of first testing if there are only chars A-Z a-z or an empty string, you might opt for running only the replacement.

Note that you have to close the character class `[^a-zA-Z]+` and you can match 1 or more times to replace it with an empty string.

```
InputValidatorChar(event:any){
  event.target.value=event.target.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]+/g, "");
}
```

Comment: I don't think we need the + there, the regExp itself means replace all non-character

Comment: @Jimmy Yes but the total number of replacements will be less if you use a quantifier to gather all matches in sequence at once.

Comment: this goes "too far" for me ^_^ there's a lot behind a Regular expression, the expression itself and the engine that executes it, we even have ReDoS, so I won't go into detail here :D